# Роутер для сервера и домашних пк

Tags: роутер

Дома стоит сервер, вещает в интернет пару сайтов. на роутере проброшены порты соответствующие. Также есть около 4-х пк, которые выходят в интернет через роутер.

Канал, не смотря на то, что он домашний - довольно широкий.Т.е. сайты работают без проблем.Тот роутер, который есть сейчас иногда бьет соединение.

Т.е. все сайты с пк иногда грузятся долго, пока его не перезагружу.Получается, что роутер не справляется с нагрузками?

1. Как определить, какой роутер нужно взять, чтобы таких проблем не было?
2. Хочется, чтобы на нем была возможность настройки максимальной загрузки канала ( к примеру на сервак 50%, на один пк 30%, на остальные пк - 20% трафика )
3. Надо, чтобы было все быстро + удобный веб интерфейс.

Посоветуйте, пожалуйста.

Comment: Какой роутер стоит сейчас?

Comment: Беспроводной маршрутизатор NETGEAR WGR614-900RUS - http://www.citilink.ru/catalog/servers_and_net_equipments/net_equipment/routers/518349/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Как определить, какой роутер нужно взять, чтобы таких проблем не было?
```

Только как следует изучив обзоры и тесты определенной модели, а так же отзывы пользователей, которые пользовались устройством хотя бы месяц. Опять же, зависит от вашего провайдера и списка предоставляемых им услуг. Если вам нужен только интернет, то тут ситуация намного проще.

```
Хочется, чтобы на нем была возможность настройки максимальной загрузки канала ( к примеру на сервак 50%, на один пк 30%, на остальные пк - 20% трафика )
```

Вообще в бюджетных роутерах эта функция обычно работает из рук вон плохо. И хорошо еще, если работает, а не мешает стабильной работе домашней сети. Как вариант, я бы рекомендовал вам посмотреть в сторону роутеров ASUS, хотя у них есть неприятные глюки, которым уже по несколько лет - тащатся с ранних моделей - но для интернета точно хватит. Вот несколько неплохих железок, которые неплохо работали на практике: D-Link DIR-620 (В особенности ревизия B1, кажется, если найдете.), ZyXEL Keenetic Giga (У них цены выше средних, при том, что зачастую железо одно с другими производителями), TP-Link TL-WR941ND неплохой девайс за небольшие деньги.Работающий контроль пропускной способности канала есть, разве что, в ASUS RT-N66U.

```
Надо, чтобы было все быстро + удобный веб интерфейс.
```

Учитывая это пожелание, выбирайте ASUS.

В идеале бы, конечно, купить какой-нибудь Mikrotik, если вы готовы в этом разбираться и настраивать его. Опять же, заплатить придется немало.

Answer (score 2):

А почему вы не хотите изменить систему подключения?Пусть канал от провайдера приходит в домашний сервер, тот, в свою очередь, поднимает сессию. На сервере гораздо проще будет настроить выход трафика на тот или иной канал далее. Плюс стабильность соединения у сервера будет больше.В этом варианте тоже есть минусы, я лет в 14-15 собирал по друзьям старые платы сетевые, что бы разделить трафик на 4 пк. Сейчас, если мне не изменяет память, можно взять одну, с несколькими портами.Но в этом варианте и плюсы: при запросах к сайтам извне будет на одну точку маршрута меньше. А как мы знаем: меньше железяк - меньше проблем.

Answer (score -2):

Через роутер сделать такие настройки не получится. Нужен прокси сервер, тогда с его помощью можно натсроить политики доступа в интернет, в том числе и ограничение трафика на канал, кому сколько можно.

В роутерах, обычно, такого не предусмотрено, так что вряд ли роутер тут поможет.

//upd т.к. комментарии закончились.

[[@bva](/users/678/bva)](/users/678/bva)

[маршрутизатор](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CC%E0%F0%F8%F0%F3%F2%E8%E7%E0%F2%EE%F0) да, он и предназначен только для разброса пакетов в сети. нафига ему еще и следить за трафиком? За это отвечают другие службы. Причем тут суровые 90е, что за бред? Линукс не умрет, и не обязательно freebsd.Если ты не знаешь - то практически во всех роутерах стоит *nix ОСь, урезанная, но стоит.

> А по поводу того, что для чегопредназначено: очень плохая практикаворотить подобное из PC

Какой смысл имея настроенный сервер, давать управление маленькой приблуде?Я изначально не рассматриваю роутер, как средство замены **сервер + ПО + HUB** для меня это всего навсего приблуда для дома, чтобы не париться дома и ставить сервер, проще поставить роутер и все будут довольны, а городить на нём какие-то политики - это не есть хорошо, и это моё мнение, оно таким и останется.Роутер он и в африке роутер, ПО это либо железка, должна служить только для одного, отправлять пакеты в нужную сторону и все. Все остальное накрученное на роутер - это просто прошивки людей, которые дома страдают от недостатка "железа", и думают как в маленькую коробку запихать много чего.

Перепрошить роутер не проблема, и добавить туда ПО для проксирования и доступа, но зачем?

[[@ArcherGodson](/users/680/archergodson)](/users/680/archergodson)Пришел плюнул в пол и ушел, зачем приходил? :)Не из компа делать роутер, а из компа делать прокси сервер, читайте слова и фразы целиком. Из компа сделать просто роутер - невыгодно, а вот если из него сделать прокси-сервер - то да.

пример: в офисе стоит сервак(контроллер домена, шара, web, ftp сервер и прочее), перед ним в инет смотрит прокси, маленькая машинка, которая разрешает/запрещает ходить по ссылкам, следить за трафиком, вообще выходить в инет и прочее.

Делать подобное на роутере дома. может и имеет смысл, делать подобное в офисе - нет, не выгодно со стороны ресурсов.

Comment: И вот интересно, кто ставит минус и не комментирует его?Я в своей практике не встречал роутеров, которые могут кидать на внутренний IP какой-то трафик, а точнее часть общего трафика.Они всегда делят его поровну. Внутри роутеров нет настроек для того чтобы этому дать 10% трафика а другому 90%.Для таких целей всегда используются прокси сервера. Отдельно взятые "машинки" на которых стоит ПО для работы с трафиком и политиками раздачи интернета и широкого канала.Так что не вижу за что поставлен адекватный минус ответу.

Comment: Утверждение "Через роутер сделать такие настройки не получится" - неверно.Также сложно считать ответ "нужно использовать специализированное ПО" полезным. Например можно перефразировать его в ответ на вопрос "Как использовать прокси-сервер?"Может есть роутеры с прокси-сервером, либо с "такими настройками" в рамках, например, шейпинга трафика, который часто в роутерах есть, допустим, в альтернативных прошивках?Поводы для минусов есть ))

Comment: Зачем из продукта, который должен только выполнять роль HUB'a делать прокси? Это бредовая идея, которая никогда не будет иметь смысл в моей жизни. Его ответ перефразировать вряд ли получится, не надо бросаться такими словами. Прочитав твой комментария с одними только знаками вопроса, сделал вывод что твой коммент просто так. Может альтернативные прошивки и есть, а есть смысл из коляски делать автомобиль?

Comment: У вас недостаточно практики:)google://routeros+mikrotikТам через вэб-интерфейс/десктоп-клиент можно вытворять многие забавные вещи

Comment: Mikrotik RouterBoard 750 (5 портов)400 грн. ~= 1568,63 RUB

Comment: и он умеет давать на порты определенный % трафика?Просто интересно стало, я никогда не буду на роутере настраивать подобные вещи. т.к. не для того он предназначен, если есть руки и свободный комп под рукой.

Comment: Да, и для чего же предназначен роутер по вашему? NAT/PAT и все?Вопрос не четкий, если имеется ввиду QoS по порту - да.А по поводу того, что для чего предназначено: очень плохая практика воротить подобное из PC, времена суровых 90-х и роутеров с FreeBSD проходят.

Comment: Не вижу смысла разводить бессмысленный флейм. Человек не получает ответ на свой вопрос, а свои минусы все уже получили.А на счёт "HUB"..  читайте вики перед использованием каждого слова, в смысле которого не уверены.Из компа делать роутер - по вашему нормально, а из роутера - роутер с прокси или роутер с шейпером - ненормально? Не... всё.. простите, что влез ))

Comment: > Причем тут суровые 90е, что за бред?В 90-х большинство мелких сетей держались на FreeBSD - ибо деньги на Cisco были мало у кого.> практически во всех роутерах стоит *nix ОСь, урезаннаяЭто где, SOHO-сектор за $100, Juniper? Вся мощь не в ОС а в железе.> имея настроенный сервер, давать управление маленькой приблудеОх, черт, а если тебе ддос снаружи приедет и фря все mbufs исчерпает?> которые дома страдают от недостатка "железа", и думают как в маленькую коробку запихать много чего.Че, правда? А Cisco ISR - это происки мировой закулисы.Кому-то и Таврия машина, спорить нет смысла

Comment: @shrek, да, Mikrotik - забавный зверек, умеет и трафик шейпить (читай делить) и ВПН сессии держать, и еще много чего другого. Попробуйте, есть дистрибутив вида RouterOS, для x86. И при чем здесь прокси-сервер? У них разные области применения с роутерами. В число задач роутера входит разделение и ограничение скорости (читай пропускной способности). Естесвенно по ряду причин это не будет работать на домашнем роутере.